# Casting Counter() to dict or list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, counter

I have a problem (more lined out here ([Best way to compare multiple key values [lists] and return multiples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75239397/best-way-to-compare-multiple-key-values-lists-and-return-multiples)))

Short summary:

Now I have several lists I want to compare, filtering out values that are present in more than one list.

I want to get:
All values that are present in more than one list
How often these values are present (so, like if they are present 2 times in every list, I want to give out these 2 - not the *total* occurences in all lists!)
And, in the end: I want to count values that are in more then one list, but not in every list.

The Setup:

In a loop, I add lists of data I want to compare to a "master" list:

```
[
['Limerick (IRE)', 'Fairyhouse (IRE)', 'Gowran Park (IRE)', 'Galway (IRE)', 'Roscommon (IRE)', 'Ballinrobe (IRE)', 'Roscommon (IRE)', 'Downpatrick (IRE)', 'Ballinrobe (IRE)', 'Curragh (IRE)', 'Naas (IRE)', 'Curragh (IRE)', 'Galway (IRE)', 'Cork (IRE)', 'Punchestown (IRE)', 'Galway (IRE)', 'Tipperary (IRE)', 'Curragh (IRE)', 'Gowran Park (IRE)', 'Cork (IRE)', 'Galway (IRE)', 'Killarney (IRE)', 'Curragh (IRE)', 'Roscommon (IRE)', 'Limerick (IRE)', 'Newton Abbot', 'Bangor-on-Dee', 'Bangor-on-Dee'],

['Newton Abbot', 'Worcester', 'Ffos Las', 'Worcester', 'Newton Abbot', 'Hereford', 'Worcester', 'Chepstow', 'Newton Abbot', 'Bangor-on-Dee', 'Stratford', 'Ffos Las', 'Huntingdon', 'Newton Abbot', 'Bangor-on-Dee'],

['Aintree', 'Market Rasen', 'Market Rasen', 'Newcastle', 'Stratford', 'Hexham', 'Cartmel', 'Stratford', 'Cartmel', 'Cartmel','Bangor-on-Dee', 'Stratford', 'Ffos Las', 'Huntingdon', 'Newton Abbot', 'Bangor-on-Dee', 'Killarney (IRE)']
]
```

There can be only 2 lists, or 20, or more to compare.

Now I try to get the multiples by Counter()and extract the most common ones
*PSEUDO CODE:*

```
        doubles= Counter()
        for w in testlist[1]:
            doubles[w] = testlist[2].count(w)
        result4 = results3.most_common(2)
        result5 = [result4[0]]
```

But this does not work as intended: Because it counts the occurences of the multiples in one list! (if in list 1 the word / number is there **one time**, but in the second one it is five times, **I still want to get only 1 as an output** - not six, or five. If it is two times in List[1] and 3 times in List[2], I want to **get 2 (+ the number/word!) **as an output, and so on)

The second problem that I have: The number of lists varies. **Can be 2, can be 20**. So *testlist[1]* is just a placeholder - I would have to check all 20 lists (or whatever the number) for occurences of the word/number that is in every list.

I can´t wrap my head around how to do this. Hopefully you can help me

***Edit***

- Added a third list for the example
- **Expected Output:**
  Comparing these lists, I would like to get something like:

- **Bangor-on-Dee: 3** (because it is in all 3 lists), **2** (because it is in all lists, at least two times)
- Killarney: **2** (because it is only in 2 of those lists), **1** (beause it is only at least once in those lists)

Comment: Please read [mre] and show: 1) short example code that we can **copy and paste, without adding or changing anything**, in order to see the exact problem. 2) **expected and actual output** for that sample (all input should be hard-coded).

Comment: I don't have a code that I can copy - the code I have does ot do what I want it to do. The two lists above are genuine the outut that is generated by the lopp. Can not just copy the loop here, because it gets its data from a database... Can I change sth ele to make it comply with the minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Given the input above, what output do you seek. An example would help.  Conceptually, what if you applied `collections.Counter()` to each of the lists then compared those results to each other?

Comment: @JonSG Did not try that yet. How can I compare collections results with each other? Sorry for asking, self taught and very much an amateure

Comment: "I don't have a code that I can copy - the code I have does ot do what I want it to do." The code that you show isn't usable *at all*. You even called it pseudocode. It's not clear, right now, how that code is supposed to relate to the question. Is it a sincere attempt that you made at solving the problem, with a concrete, specific problem that you are asking about? is it a vague sketch of things that you think the right code might contain? Just what?

Comment: For example: "The Setup: In a loop" - right there, **why not show the loop**?

Comment: Because the loop is basicly :  for _ in SQL-Result: list.append(track)  - as explained in the linked post, where I asked if appending to a dict or list would be better - and what the best way would be to archieve my goal. I am not sure if this is really helpful for the question how to compare those lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prior to any optimization, I would break this task into three steps,

1. count the occurrences of each key in each row
2. merge the counts based on key
3. print the results based on what we find out about the counts after
   merging them

```py
import collections
import json

data = [
    ['Limerick (IRE)', 'Fairyhouse (IRE)', 'Gowran Park (IRE)', 'Galway (IRE)', 'Roscommon (IRE)', 'Ballinrobe (IRE)', 'Roscommon (IRE)', 'Downpatrick (IRE)', 'Ballinrobe (IRE)', 'Curragh (IRE)', 'Naas (IRE)', 'Curragh (IRE)', 'Galway (IRE)', 'Cork (IRE)', 'Punchestown (IRE)', 'Galway (IRE)', 'Tipperary (IRE)', 'Curragh (IRE)', 'Gowran Park (IRE)', 'Cork (IRE)', 'Galway (IRE)', 'Killarney (IRE)', 'Curragh (IRE)', 'Roscommon (IRE)', 'Limerick (IRE)', 'Newton Abbot', 'Bangor-on-Dee', 'Bangor-on-Dee'],
    ['Newton Abbot', 'Worcester', 'Ffos Las', 'Worcester', 'Newton Abbot', 'Hereford', 'Worcester', 'Chepstow', 'Newton Abbot', 'Bangor-on-Dee', 'Stratford', 'Ffos Las', 'Huntingdon', 'Newton Abbot', 'Bangor-on-Dee'],
    ['Aintree', 'Market Rasen', 'Market Rasen', 'Newcastle', 'Stratford', 'Hexham', 'Cartmel', 'Stratford', 'Cartmel', 'Cartmel','Bangor-on-Dee', 'Stratford', 'Ffos Las', 'Huntingdon', 'Newton Abbot', 'Bangor-on-Dee', 'Killarney (IRE)']
]

## ---------------------
## Gather the per row counts
## ---------------------
data_counted = [
    dict(collections.Counter(row))
    for row
    in data
]
#print(json.dumps(data_counted, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
## ---------------------

## ---------------------
## merge the rows on name
## ---------------------
data_counted_combined = {}
for row in data_counted:
    for name, count in row.items():
        target = data_counted_combined.setdefault(name, []) ## make sure this key is initialized
        target.append(count)
#print(json.dumps(data_counted_combined, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
## ---------------------

## ---------------------
## Generate the final result (sorted for fun)
## ---------------------
for key, value in sorted(data_counted_combined.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    print(f"\"{key}\" appears in { len(value) } list(s) a minimum of { min(value) } times.")
## ---------------------
```

This produces the following:

```
"Aintree" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 1 times.
"Ballinrobe (IRE)" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 2 times.
"Bangor-on-Dee" appears in 3 list(s) a minimum of 2 times.
"Cartmel" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 3 times.
"Chepstow" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 1 times.
"Cork (IRE)" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 2 times.
"Curragh (IRE)" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 4 times.
"Downpatrick (IRE)" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 1 times.
"Fairyhouse (IRE)" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 1 times.
"Ffos Las" appears in 2 list(s) a minimum of 1 times.
"Galway (IRE)" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 4 times.
"Gowran Park (IRE)" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 2 times.
"Hereford" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 1 times.
"Hexham" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 1 times.
"Huntingdon" appears in 2 list(s) a minimum of 1 times.
"Killarney (IRE)" appears in 2 list(s) a minimum of 1 times.
"Limerick (IRE)" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 2 times.
"Market Rasen" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 2 times.
"Naas (IRE)" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 1 times.
"Newcastle" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 1 times.
"Newton Abbot" appears in 3 list(s) a minimum of 1 times.
"Punchestown (IRE)" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 1 times.
"Roscommon (IRE)" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 3 times.
"Stratford" appears in 2 list(s) a minimum of 1 times.
"Tipperary (IRE)" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 1 times.
"Worcester" appears in 1 list(s) a minimum of 3 times.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked with this code and I think I got what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

You can first check if the element is in both lists, then get the minimum count of the element in both lists:

```py
arr1 = ['Newton Abbot', 'Worcester', 'Ffos Las', 'Worcester', 'Newton Abbot', 'Hereford', 'Worcester', 'Chepstow',
        'Newton Abbot', 'Bangor-on-Dee', 'Stratford', 'Ffos Las', 'Huntingdon', 'Newton Abbot', 'Bangor-on-Dee']
arr2 = ['Aintree', 'Market Rasen', 'Market Rasen', 'Newcastle', 'Stratford', 'Hexham', 'Cartmel', 'Stratford',
        'Cartmel', 'Cartmel', 'Bangor-on-Dee', 'Stratford', 'Ffos Las', 'Huntingdon', 'Newton Abbot', 'Bangor-on-Dee']

all_lists = [arr1, arr2]

occurences = {}

for x in all_lists[0]:
    # check if x is in all_lists
    x_in_all_lists = True
    counts = []
    for arr in all_lists:
        if x not in arr:
            x_in_all_lists = False
            break
        counts.append(arr.count(x))
    # get the least number of times x occurs in the lists of all_lists
    if x_in_all_lists:
        occurences[x] = min(counts)

for k, v in occurences.items():
    print(f'{k}\t{v}')
```

Output:

```
Newton Abbot    1
Ffos Las        1
Bangor-on-Dee   2
Stratford       1
Huntingdon      1
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for the example above! I edited the question a little as suggested by the comments. Does this work if I add more lists to the all_lists and all_lists[0] has no matches with the following lists? I could make a list of all the tracks and make this all_lists[0] and then use your script to count them.. would that work?

Comment: @Phil Since you said that you only wanted elements that appear in all lists, only fetching elements from all_lists[0] works. Because, if an element is not in all_lists[0], it is not in every list in all_lists.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a breakdown of the code:

1. Count the frequency of each word in each list (`counters`)
2. Collect all the words from all the lists, and generate the set of words that we can expect to appear in any of these lists (`all_words`)
3. Define a dict `maxFreqDict` which maps words in `all_words` to tuples `(a,b)` where
   `a` = the number of lists this word appears in
   `b` = the minimum number of occurrences of this word (among the lists where it appears)
   Initialize each `a` to 0 and `b` to some large number which we later shrink down.
4. Run `counters` through a reduce function where for each possible `word`, we update the tuple `(a,b)` if `word` is present in the current list, otherwise do nothing.
5. Print out the result (the final state of `maxFreqDict`)

*Note:* `more_itertools` is an installed package that extends the utilities of the built-in `itertools`. `more_itertools.flatten(array2d)` can be replaced with `itertools.chain(*array2d)` if you don't want to install an additional package.

```py
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce
from more_itertools import flatten
from pprint import pprint

lists = [
    ['Limerick (IRE)', 'Fairyhouse (IRE)', 'Gowran Park (IRE)', 'Galway (IRE)', 'Roscommon (IRE)',
     'Ballinrobe (IRE)', 'Roscommon (IRE)', 'Downpatrick (IRE)', 'Ballinrobe (IRE)', 'Curragh (IRE)',
     'Naas (IRE)', 'Curragh (IRE)', 'Galway (IRE)', 'Cork (IRE)', 'Punchestown (IRE)', 'Galway (IRE)',
     'Tipperary (IRE)', 'Curragh (IRE)', 'Gowran Park (IRE)', 'Cork (IRE)', 'Galway (IRE)', 'Killarney (IRE)',
     'Curragh (IRE)', 'Roscommon (IRE)', 'Limerick (IRE)', 'Newton Abbot', 'Bangor-on-Dee', 'Bangor-on-Dee'],
    ['Newton Abbot', 'Worcester', 'Ffos Las', 'Worcester', 'Newton Abbot', 'Hereford', 'Worcester', 'Chepstow',
        'Newton Abbot', 'Bangor-on-Dee', 'Stratford', 'Ffos Las', 'Huntingdon', 'Newton Abbot', 'Bangor-on-Dee'],
    ['Aintree', 'Market Rasen', 'Market Rasen', 'Newcastle', 'Stratford', 'Hexham', 'Cartmel', 'Stratford', 'Cartmel',
        'Cartmel', 'Bangor-on-Dee', 'Stratford', 'Ffos Las', 'Huntingdon', 'Newton Abbot', 'Bangor-on-Dee', 'Killarney (IRE)']
]


# counter the frequency of each word in each list
counters = [Counter(l) for l in lists]
# find all the unique words across all lists
all_words = set(flatten(c.keys() for c in counters))

def reduceFunc(maxFreqDict: dict[str, tuple[int, int]], curCounter: Counter) -> dict[str, tuple[int, int]]:
    for word in maxFreqDict.keys():
        if word in curCounter:
            # listFeq: in how many lists this word appears
            # wordFreq: the min number of occurrences of this word (among the lists that it appears in) 
            listFreq, wordFreq = maxFreqDict[word]
            minWordFreq = min(wordFreq, curCounter[word])
            maxFreqDict[word] = (listFreq + 1, minWordFreq)
        else:
            pass
    return maxFreqDict

# start with a large number as the frequency of each word
# so we can find the actual frequency in reduceFunc using min()
maxFreqDict = {word: (0, 1e9) for word in all_words}
res = reduce(reduceFunc, counters, maxFreqDict)

pprint(res)
```

This should produce the following output:

```py
{'Aintree': (1, 1),
 'Ballinrobe (IRE)': (1, 2),
 'Bangor-on-Dee': (3, 2),
 'Cartmel': (1, 3),
 'Chepstow': (1, 1),
 'Cork (IRE)': (1, 2),
 'Curragh (IRE)': (1, 4),
 'Downpatrick (IRE)': (1, 1),        
 'Fairyhouse (IRE)': (1, 1),
 'Ffos Las': (2, 1),
 'Galway (IRE)': (1, 4),
 'Gowran Park (IRE)': (1, 2),        
 'Hereford': (1, 1),
 'Hexham': (1, 1),
 'Huntingdon': (2, 1),
 'Killarney (IRE)': (2, 1),
 'Limerick (IRE)': (1, 2),
 'Market Rasen': (1, 2),
 'Naas (IRE)': (1, 1),
 'Newcastle': (1, 1),
 'Newton Abbot': (3, 1),
 'Punchestown (IRE)': (1, 1),        
 'Roscommon (IRE)': (1, 3),
 'Stratford': (2, 1),
 'Tipperary (IRE)': (1, 1),
 'Worcester': (1, 3)}
```